# UWP ContainerFromItem returning null for a GridViewItem

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have following GridView

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="gird_view" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind workers}"
    ContainerContentChanging="gird_view_ContainerContentChanging">
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Worker">
            <local:WorkerControl ViewModel="{x:Bind}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I am trying following code

```
private async void gird_view_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    GridViewItem item = args.ItemContainer as GridViewItem;

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    var _Container = gird_view.ContainerFromItem(item);
    if (_Container == null)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

`_Container` is always coming as null with or without delay. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridViewItem` is the container:

```
GridViewItem item = args.ItemContainer as GridViewItem;
```

To get the data object for that container, i.e. your `Worker` object, you should use the `Item` property:

```
Worker worker = args.Item as Worker;
```

There should be no need to use the `ContainerFromItem` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`_Container` is always null because the parameter of the `ContainerFromItem` method should be a data model class. This method is used to get the corresponding `GridViewItem` based on the given data object. In your scenario, if you want to get a `GridViewItem`, you should use it like this:

```
var _Container = gird_view.ContainerFromItem(WorkerObject);
```

But I'm confused about your logic, actually you've already got the `GridViewItem` via the `args.ItemContainer`. There is no need to call `ContainerFromItem` method again.